# ghci error: "No breakpoints found at that location."

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghci

I am attempting to follow the [ghci debugger documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html) to my stack project, and have entered the repl by running `$ stack ghci`. When I try to set a breakpoint at line 207 in module `Api.Checklist`, I get the following error.

```
> :break Api.Checklist 207
No breakpoints found at that location.
```

The breakpoint is not set, as shown by the empty result of `:show breaks`.

```
> :show breaks
No active breakpoints.
```

Why does `> :break Api.Checklist 207` fail to set the breakpoint?

---

EDIT:

as requested, the content of Api.Checklist is below, where line `207` is the line reading `checklistAnswerPG entryId apiAnswer =`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExtendedDefaultRules  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}

module Api.Checklist where

import           Control.Monad            (mapM, mapM_)
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class   (liftIO)
import           Data.Aeson               (FromJSON, Value(..),
                                           toJSON, encode)
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict      as M
import           Data.Text                (Text, pack)
import           Data.Time.Clock          (UTCTime, getCurrentTime)
import           GHC.Generics             (Generic)
import qualified Opaleye                  as O
import           Servant

import           Api.Shared
import           App
import           Models.Checklist
import           Models.ChecklistAnswer
import           Models.ChecklistEntry
import           Models.ChecklistQuestion
import           Models.ChecklistTemplate
import           Models.Validation        (Errors(..), Validatable,
                                           Validation,
                                           ValidationResult (Failure, Success),
                                           errors, failure, keyToField,
                                           validate, validateEntity)
import           Queries.Checklist
import           Types.JWTUser

data ApiAnswer = ApiAnswer { questionId :: Int, answer :: Maybe Bool }
  deriving (Generic)
data ApiChecklistEntryWrite = ApiChecklistEntryWrite { answers :: [ApiAnswer] }
  deriving (Generic)

instance FromJSON ApiAnswer
instance FromJSON ApiChecklistEntryWrite
instance Validatable ApiChecklistEntryWrite where
  validateEntity entry = do
    mapM_ validateAnswer $ answers entry

    where
      validateAnswer :: ApiAnswer -> Validation
      validateAnswer apiAnswer = do
        case answer (apiAnswer :: ApiAnswer) of
          Just _ ->
            return ()

          Nothing ->
            failure (pack $ "answers[questionId=" ++ show (questionId (apiAnswer :: ApiAnswer)) ++ "]") ["must not be null"]


type ChecklistAPI = Get '[JSON] ChecklistRead
               :<|> ReqBody '[JSON] TemplateChecklist :> Patch '[JSON] ChecklistRead
               :<|> "entries" :> Get '[JSON] [ChecklistEntryRead]
               :<|> "entries" :> Capture "checklistEntryId" Int :> Get '[JSON] ChecklistEntryRead
               :<|> "entries" :> ReqBody '[JSON] ApiChecklistEntryWrite :> Post '[JSON] ChecklistEntryRead
               :<|> "questions" :> Get '[JSON] [ChecklistQuestionRead]
               :<|> "entries" :> Capture "entryId" Int :> "answers" :> Get '[JSON] [Value]


checklistAPI :: Servant.Proxy ChecklistAPI
checklistAPI = Servant.Proxy


checklistServer :: JWTUser -> Int -> ServerT ChecklistAPI AppM
checklistServer jwtUser checklistId' = getChecklist jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> updateChecklist jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> getChecklistEntries jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> getChecklistEntry jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> createChecklistEntry jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> getChecklistQuestions jwtUser checklistId'
                                 :<|> getChecklistAnswers jwtUser checklistId'


getChecklist :: JWTUser -> Int -> AppM ChecklistRead
getChecklist _ = singleQuery . checklistQuery


updateChecklist :: JWTUser -> Int -> TemplateChecklist -> AppM ChecklistRead
updateChecklist jwtUser checklistId' template' = withTransaction $ do
  case validate template' of
    Success ->
      go

    Failure es ->
      throwError $ err422 { errBody = encode $ Errors { errors = es } }

  where
    go = do
      originalChecklist <- singleQuery (checklistQuery checklistId')
      let facilityId' = facilityId (originalChecklist :: ChecklistRead)
          checklistWrite = ChecklistWrite { facilityId = facilityId'
                                          , name = name (template' :: TemplateChecklist)
                                          }

      updatedChecklist <- liftIO . checklistToPG $ checklistWrite
      result <- update
                jwtUser
                (Just facilityId')
                checklistTable
                (\_ -> updatedChecklist { Models.Checklist.checklistId = Just $ O.pgInt4 checklistId' })
                (\org -> (Models.Checklist.checklistId org) O..== O.pgInt4 checklistId')

      case result of
        Left err ->
          handleSqlError (keyToField template') err

        Right savedChecklist -> do
          updateQuestions savedChecklist
          return savedChecklist

    updateQuestions savedChecklist = do
      let facilityId' = facilityId (savedChecklist :: ChecklistRead)
      now <- liftIO getCurrentTime
      archivePreviousQuestions now facilityId'
      mapM_ (createQuestion savedChecklist now) $ questions template'
      return ()

    createQuestion :: ChecklistRead -> UTCTime -> TemplateQuestion -> AppM ChecklistQuestionRead
    createQuestion savedChecklist now question' = do
      let facilityId' = facilityId (savedChecklist :: ChecklistRead)
      newChecklistQuestion <-
        liftIO . checklistQuestionToPG now $ ChecklistQuestionWrite
                                             (checklistId (savedChecklist :: ChecklistRead))
                                             (question (question' :: TemplateQuestion))
                                             (description (question' :: TemplateQuestion))
                                             (questionType (question' :: TemplateQuestion))
                                             (position (question' :: TemplateQuestion))
      createOr500
        (keyToField template')
        jwtUser
        (Just facilityId')
        checklistQuestionTable
        newChecklistQuestion

    archivePreviousQuestions now facilityId' = do
      previousQuestions <- query (checklistQuestionsByChecklistAndTimeQuery checklistId' now)
      mapM_ (archiveQuestion now facilityId') previousQuestions

    archiveQuestion :: UTCTime -> Int -> ChecklistQuestionRead -> AppM ChecklistQuestionRead
    archiveQuestion now facilityId' question' = do
      updatedQuestion <- liftIO . checklistQuestionReadToWrite $ question'
      updateOr500 (keyToField template') jwtUser (Just facilityId') checklistQuestionTable
                (\_ -> updatedQuestion { effectiveTo = O.pgUTCTime now })
                (\q -> Models.ChecklistQuestion.checklistQuestionId q O..== O.pgInt4 (Models.ChecklistQuestion.checklistQuestionId question'))



getChecklistEntry :: JWTUser -> Int -> Int -> AppM ChecklistEntryRead
getChecklistEntry _ _ = singleQuery . checklistEntryQuery


getChecklistEntries :: JWTUser -> Int -> AppM [ChecklistEntryRead]
getChecklistEntries _  = query . checklistEntryByChecklistQuery


getChecklistQuestions :: JWTUser -> Int -> AppM [ChecklistQuestionRead]
getChecklistQuestions _ checklistId' =
  query . checklistQuestionsByChecklistAndTimeQuery checklistId' =<< liftIO getCurrentTime


getChecklistAnswers :: JWTUser -> Int -> Int -> AppM [Value]
getChecklistAnswers _ _ id =
  fmap buildJson <$> (query $ checklistAnswersWithQuestionForChecklistEntryQuery id)

  where
    buildJson :: (ChecklistAnswerRead, ChecklistQuestionRead) -> Value
    buildJson (a, q) =
      let
        Object jsonAnswer = toJSON a
        jsonQuestion = toJSON q
      in
        Object (M.insert "checklistQuestion" jsonQuestion jsonAnswer)


createChecklistEntry :: JWTUser -> Int -> ApiChecklistEntryWrite -> AppM ChecklistEntryRead
createChecklistEntry jwtUser cId checklistEntryWrite = do
  checklist <- singleQuery (checklistQuery cId) :: AppM ChecklistRead
  withTransaction $ validateAndCreate (go $ facilityId (checklist :: ChecklistRead)) checklistEntryWrite

  where
    go facId = do
      newChecklistEntry <- liftIO . checklistEntryToPG $ ChecklistEntryWrite cId
      savedChecklistEntry <- create jwtUser (Just facId) checklistEntryTable newChecklistEntry

      case savedChecklistEntry of
        Right checklistEntry -> do
          let newChecklistAnswerPG = checklistAnswerPG $ checklistEntryId (checklistEntry :: ChecklistEntryRead)

          createdAnswers <- mapM newChecklistAnswerPG $ answers checklistEntryWrite
          results <- mapM (create jwtUser (Just facId) checklistAnswerTable) createdAnswers :: AppM [DbResult ChecklistAnswerRead]
          case all isRight results of
            True ->
              return checklistEntry
            False ->
              throwError $ err500 { errBody = "one or more answers failed to save" }

        Left _ ->
          throwError err500

    checklistAnswerPG entryId apiAnswer =
      case answer (apiAnswer :: ApiAnswer) of
        Just a ->
          liftIO $ checklistAnswerToPG $ ChecklistAnswerWrite { checklistEntryId = entryId
                                                              , checklistQuestionId = questionId apiAnswer
                                                              , answer = boolToText a
                                                              }
        Nothing ->
          throwError $ err500 { errBody = "got a null answer, validations should have happened by now" }

    boolToText :: Bool -> Text
    boolToText True  = "true"
    boolToText False = "false"
```

Comment: What are the contents of `Api.Checklist`?

Comment: @user2407038 contents of `Api.Checklist` are posted as requested.

Comment: Assuming I've read the code correctly, line 207 contains precisely `checklistAnswerPG entryId apiAnswer =`. From the docs: "When a breakpoint is set on a particular line, GHCi sets the breakpoint on the leftmost subexpression" - is there an expression on that line at all?

Comment: @user2407038 I guess not. But I have been able to set breakpoints on top-level function definitions before -- is this case different because the function is defined within a `where` clause?

Comment: You are not setting a breakpoint on a function, you are setting a breakpoint on a line. There are multiple different syntaxes for setting breakpoints, and they have different semantics. The syntax you are asking about doesn't permit setting a breakpoint on a declaration, top-level or local. I would reiterate once more, but I feel that the [docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#setting-breakpoints) explain it quite clearly.

Comment: @user2407038 okay, thank you for the help.